# One way Deep linking in PureMVC, How and When?

Tags: actionscript-3, puremvc

A project requirement is that it be 1 way deeplinkable(a specific query string will load a section within the swf).

I have a URLProxy that I use for all external linking.
It makes sense to me to put the query string logic in this proxy.

So in the constructor, I check for a querystring, and then send a notification if it equals a predefined value.

One problem with this is that I'd like to predefine this query string key value I am checking against in an external xml file.

So another proxy, loads-parses this config xml, then the URL proxy checks against this.

Is there a better approach to what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

not very clean question for me, if you can please explain more detailed,
and for now:

maybe there are some sense to send something like GET\POST or just variables to your proxy, but where from you are calling it, its another one question to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party here, but if anyone needs this, you should use `swfAddress` to deep link in to flash via the url.

https://github.com/danro/swfaddress-as3/blob/master/SWFAddress.as